# What's exactly ntc form in tf-idf vector space?

Tags: python, nlp, tf-idf

I have a collection of text documents. I've been asked to show each document in tf-idf vector space and in ntc form and then, train a svm model based on documents' vectors in python. What does ntc exactly mean here?

I Found that it's the same as tf-idf weights with one step of normalization which is called "cosine normalization". But i can't find information about such thing. I found "cosine similarity" which is in my idea different from "cosine normalization". Are they the same? And how can i create this vector in python?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the **sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer**,
scikit learn is a bib in python used for training machine learning model,
it is easy and very useful,

Comment: Prior to this issue, i wanted to know what does "ntc" and "cosine normalization" signify here :\